# How many widgets per application are supported in Android?

Tags: android

Can I have more than one widget per app on home screen of Android for the same application? That is to display at once on home.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Here is the [reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) from Google.

Comment: this does not seem to address how many different widgets can be added to the home page per application.

Answer (score 0):

The user can add as many widgets of your application as he want.

Comment: Even if these are different widget types?

Comment: What I am trying to verify is if these separate widgets can all be added to the home page at the same time.

Comment: At the same time no, they will be added one by one.

Comment: And they'll have differents ids